# node js Undefined elements in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having a problem with an example project for an online course I'm taking.  When I go to /fakeAnimalData I get the elements animal and fact to show in the body of the HTML and in my terminal (but not in the console, where it should appear--why isn't it appearing?) and then when I go to /addAnimal, after I submit the form, I see fav in the body of the HTML (but not in the console--why isn't it appearing?) but my big problem is that in the object returned in the terminal, animal and fact are undefined.  Also, for some reason, fact is showing up as facts--why is this?

The goal is to get the data from /fakeAnimalData to appear in the object returned in the terminal from /addAnimal, so I get all three elements returned and populated-- animal, fact and fav.  I want the object returned in the terminal AND the console, but right now the object is only being returned in the terminal.

What am I doing wrong?  This is my code:

server.js:

```
projectData = {};

/* Express to run server and routes */
const express = require('express');

/* Start up an instance of app */
const app = express();

/* Dependencies */
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
/* Middleware*/
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

/* Initialize the main project folder*/
app.use(express.static('project1'));

const port = 8000;
/* Spin up the server*/
const server = app.listen(port, listening);
 function listening(){
    // console.log(server);
    console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`);
  };

// GET route

const animalData = [];
const fakeData = {animal: "lion", fact: "a lion's roar can be heard five miles away"};

app.get('/fakeAnimalData', getFakeData);

function getFakeData(req, res) {
  res.send(fakeData)
  console.log(fakeData)
};

app.get('/all', getData);

function getData(req, res){
  res.send(animalData)
  console.log(animalData)
}

// function sendData (request, response) {
//  response.send(projectData);
// };

// POST route
app.post('/add', callBack);

function callBack(req,res){
  res.send('POST received');
}



// POST an animal
const data = [];


  // TODO-Call Function



app.route('/addAnimal')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
  })
  .post(addAnimal)

function addAnimal(req, res){

  newEntry = {
    animal: req.body.animal,
    facts: req.body.fact,
    fav: req.body.fav
  }

  data.push(req.body);
//  res.status(200).send(req.body);
  animalData.push(newEntry)
  res.send(animalData)
  console.log(animalData)
};
```

app.js:

```
function performActuion(e){
const fav = document.getElementById('fav').value;



const getAnimal = async (url) =>{
  const res = await fetch(url);
  try {
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log()
  }
};

/* Function to POST data */
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
      const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });

      try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        // console.log(newData);
        return newData.json()
        console.log(await response.json());
        return await response.json()
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      // appropriately handle the error
      };
  };

  // TODO-Call Function
getAnimal('/fakeAnimalData')
.then(async function(data){
    console.log(data);
  let res = await postData('/addAnimal', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: fav});
  console.log(res);
});
};
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

EDIT:

I think the problem is that this part of the code isn't working:

```
getAnimal('/fakeAnimalData')
.then(async function(data){
    console.log(data);
  let res = await postData('/addAnimal', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: fav});
  console.log(res);
});
};
```

/fakeAnimalData returns {"animal": "lion", "fact": "a lion's roar can be heard five miles away"} (but only in the body of the HTML, not in the console) and I want the above code to work in conjunction with the below code to transfer the data from /fakeAnimalData to the data that is returned when I submit the form on /addAnimal so the object returned is {"animal": "lion", "fact": "a lion's roar can can be heard five miles away", "fav": "data returned from form"}.  The whole point of this is to simulate making an API call from an outside API.

```
function performActuion(e){
const fav = document.getElementById('fav').value;



const getAnimal = async (url) =>{
  const res = await fetch(url);
  try {
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log()
  }
};
```

EDIT 2:

I'm getting closer.  I had a piece of code in the wrong place.  Now when I submit the code I get all three elements of the object to appear in the body of the HTML, but when I look in the terminal I still see animal and fact as undefined even though those elements do appear in the result of the body of the htmL.  app.js now looks like this:

```
function performActuion(e){
const fav = document.getElementById('fav').value;

getAnimal('/fakeAnimalData')
.then(async function(data){
    console.log(data);
  let res = await postData('/addAnimal', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: fav});
  console.log(res);
});
};

const getAnimal = async (url) =>{
  const res = await fetch(url);
  try {
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log()
  }
};

/* Function to POST data */
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
      const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });

      try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        // console.log(newData);
        return newData.json()
        console.log(await response.json());
        return await response.json()
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      // appropriately handle the error
      };
  };

  // TODO-Call Function
getAnimal('/fakeAnimalData')
.then(async function(data){
    console.log(data);
  let res = await postData('/addAnimal', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: fav});
  console.log(res);
});
```

I feel like I'm close but not quite there yet.

EDIT 3:

I think the problem is with this code.  It's not returning all the data that is being passed to the function:

```
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
      const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });

      try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        // console.log(newData);
        return newData
        console.log(await response.json());
        return await response.json()
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      // appropriately handle the error
      };
  };
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem https://shallowtightformula--five-nine.repl.co/fakeAnimalData

Comment: I don't really think that entire lump of code is necessary to demonstrate your problem. If you manage to shrink it to minimal required block (preferrably, posted as executable snippet) that will increase your chances to get relevant answer **dramatically**.

Comment: You call it “facts” when you build the new object in addAnimal

Comment: ok, I think I isolated the two parts of the code that aren't doing what they are supposed to do.  Please see my edit.

Comment: You're sending a response before logging to the console which might be an issue here.

Comment: I'm getting close.  I had a chunk of code in the wrong place.  Please see my second edit.